# Defining events on F5 , back and forward browser keys pressed with HostListener

Tags: angular, events, refresh

I'm trying to target refresh, back and forward browser key events with HostListener.

Started by using keypress and popstate but not having any luck.

If I use `beforeunload` the event is triggered but I need different actions for each situation.

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event']) savePageInfo($event : any) {
  if($event.key === 'F5') 
}
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event']) onPopState($event:any) {}

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) onunload($event: any) {}
```

Any suggestions on how to procede?